# PHP Search and check for value in Array Object

Tags: php, arrays

I have the  following data that I would like to search through :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4860
            [module] => Clients
            [level] => 2
            [order] => 1
            [controller] => home
            [function] => clients
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => Manage the partner clients in the  system
            [span_class] => label btn-metis-6 client_info
            [icon_class] => icon-user-md icon-2x
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 6
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4865
            [module] => Appointments
            [level] => 3
            [order] => 1
            [controller] => home
            [function] => appointments
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => View and manage all active Appointments in the  System
            [span_class] => label label-default appointments_info
            [icon_class] => icon-user
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 16
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4870
            [module] => Broadcast Report
            [level] => 7
            [order] => 1
            [controller] => home
            [function] => broadcast_report
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => View all the  Broadcasts that have been sent out to the clients
            [span_class] => label label-default broadcast_info
            [icon_class] => icon-table
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 53
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4861
            [module] => Add Client
            [level] => 2
            [order] => 2
            [controller] => home
            [function] => client
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => Add new client to the  system and at the  same time book first appointment for the  client.
            [span_class] => 
            [icon_class] => icon-user icon-2x
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 8
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4863
            [module] => My Facilities
            [level] => 7
            [order] => 2
            [controller] => admin
            [function] => my_facilities
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => Facilities manager is used to add facilities to a partner's group of Facilities
            [span_class] => label label-default facility_info
            [icon_class] => icon-h-sign
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 12
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4869
            [module] => Adolescents
            [level] => 5
            [order] => 2
            [controller] => home
            [function] => adolescents
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => View the Adolescent client groups 
            [span_class] => label btn-metis-6  groups_info
            [icon_class] => icon-calendar-empty
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 38
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4858
            [module] => Users
            [level] => 6
            [order] => 3
            [controller] => admin
            [function] => users
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => User management windows , used to Add, Edit or Delete(mark as In Active) users in the system 
            [span_class] => label btn-metis-4 users_info
            [icon_class] => icon-user icon-2x
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 3
            [role_id] => 4
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4864
            [module] => Deactivated
            [level] => 7
            [order] => 3
            [controller] => home
            [function] => deactivated
            [status] => Active
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [time_stamp] => 2017-08-02 09:39:01
            [description] => List of clients who opted out from the  SMS services.
            [span_class] => label label-default  deactivated_info
            [icon_class] => icon-user
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 
            [partner_id] => 
            [user_id] => 264
            [module_id] => 15
            [role_id] => 4
        )

)
```

I would like to search through the  array and check if level exists and what is the  value of the  index. 
I tried the following :

```
$number = array_column($array, 'level');
 $found_key = array_search('2', $number);

              But I get no response .
```

Any help on how I check through the  array and check if level exists and what is the value that it's holding?

Comment: You mean object right?

Comment: @Script47 Yes object

Comment: can you add an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your array with something like that:

```
$filterBy = '2';
$newArray = array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return ($var['level'] == $filterBy); });

print_r($newArray);

$names = array_column($newArray, 'id');

print_r($names);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is an object, you'll need to cast the them to an array type if you wish to use those array based functions on them:

```
<?php
$x = new stdClass();
$x->y = 'test';
$x->z = 'more testing';

$array = (array) $x; ----> Is now an array.
?>
```

> (array) - cast to array

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` loop

Like this.

```
foreach ($array in $key => $value){
   if($value["level"] != ''){
      echo $value["level"];
   }    
}
```